# taxonomy/term/% says "page not found"

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Currently, all URLs to taxonomy/term/% say "page not found."

Here's what i did the last minutes:

- My taxonomy view consisted of very large entry;I just did the usual customized taxonomy/term/% view: I first duplicated the original one, and then I deactivated it.
- In my custom module, in hook_nodeapi(), I checked if the current URL is /node/*, and in the case it's not (e.g. it's a taxonomy view), I skipped my custom additions (lookup content in a file). It worked fine, with small "teaser" entries on the tax.page.
- I changed the page size in view, increased it, and exposed it. Then I recognized some minor things that were not well done, deleted the view, and recopied it again.

Now all URLs to taxonomy/term/% say returns the "page not found" error.
I can't figure out why. The cache is cleared, and I am logged in as administrator.

Preview in Views UI works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had active a second view with the path defined...